# Can Capacity Down disrupt Accelerator's esper powers?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index, a-certain-scientific-railgun, a-certain-scientific-accelerator

Capacity Down is a device that produces a sound that can disrupt an esper. It was used in the anime series against Kongou Mitsuko, Misaka Mikoto, Shirai Kuroko etc.

My question is, does this device work against Accelerator, whose power can deflect any vectors who reachs him, and being sound waves used by the device also vectors?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as Capacity Down functions off of sound waves the answer actually depends.

If Accelerator is aware of it or is for any other reason reflecting sound waves away from him then no, it won't have any effect. If however he is taken by surprise and is not reflecting sound waves then it would work. He would hear it and it would prevent him from using his abilities to reflect it away from and also shut down his other abilities as well.

Comment: What about if his chocker was not active?

Comment: @кяαzєя if his choker is not active he doesn't really have much in the way of powers to begin with usually. But he definitely couldn't reflect/deflect the soundwaves away from himself without it (assuming post-nerf, cus he obviously didn't need it pre-nerf)

Comment: I see that this now says it needs references but I'm not sure what forts of references I can add for a hypothetical event that hasn't happened.

Comment: Something similar happens in the Three Stories Arc. Whether or not the choker's Esper mode is active is one factor. Accelerator's modified modern cane is also another factor. This question if objectively answerable if you cite from these sources. Thus far your answer is purely anecdotal and could use better citations from canonical sources.

Comment: Accelerator has deflected sound waves. You can reference that. If you can find when he did it, just list the episode number and title, or volume and chapter, and a brief description of the event.

Comment: If you can find a good description of how Capacity Down works, I'd directly quote that as well. Particularly if there is textual evidence that supports your theory ( for instance, if it says the sound has to be heard by the esper).